# Jest cannot find node module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to use [Radar](https://radar.com/documentation) for autocomplete and address validation, but am running into the following error when running jest with typescript:

```
 Test suite failed to run. Cannot find module 'radar-sdk-js' from 'fetchAutocomplete/index.tsx'
```

In that file, I am importing radar-sdk-js as `import Radar from 'radar-sdk-js'`

I'm using Next js and my jest config (using jest ^29.5.0)

```
// jest.config.js

const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
});

const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
    '^@/pages/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/pages/$1',
    '^@/radar/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/radar/$1',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Radar. It works fine when I include it as html rather than using yarn.
I tried adding a module name mapper of `^radar-sdk-js': '<rootDir>/node_modules/radar-sdk-js'` but that isn't working.

Edit:

If i add the following, i at least get a more distinct error:

```
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import maplibregl from 'maplibre-gl';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

```
// jest.config.js
 moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
    '^@/pages/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/pages/$1',
    '^@/radar/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/radar/$1',
    '^radar-sdk-js': '<rootDir>/node_modules/radar-sdk-js/dist/radar.js', // Add this otherwise tests will fail. This didn't need to be added before(?)
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(radar-sdk-js)/)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|mjs)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
```